# Can I redirect a worker thread to do a different job in middle of processing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I have this Worker class that I use for multithreading.

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void , String>
{
    private int optionOfWork;
    public Worker(int int optionOfWork)
    {
        this.optionOfWork = optionOfWork;
    }
    ...
    ...
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        switch (optionOfWork) {
            case 1:
            {
                ...
                ...
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                ...
                something...
            }
            default:
            {
                ...
            }
        }

    }//doInBackground()

}//Worker class
```

Say I create a worker thread instance:

```
Worker worker1 = new Worker(1);
```

and I start it using `worker1.excute();`
Now the worker immediately starts the `doInBackground()` method in the case of **optionOfWork = 1**.

Can I change (from the main thread) the worker's job in the middle of excution like this:

```
worker1.setOptionOfWork(2);
worker1.excute();
```

or maybe:

```
worker1.setOptionOfWork(2);
worker1.doInBackground();
```

and it will stop it's current excution and start excuting the case: **optionOfWork = 2** of the doInBackground() method?

Comment: No, you'd at least have to interrupt the worker, and it'll most likely lose all that he processeud up to that point. Unless you specifically code interruptibility and processing checkpoints, at which point it'd no longer be the default worker.

Comment: Also, the `doInBackground()` forces _your calling thread_ to execute the computation.

Comment: I appreciate this feedback on my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misconception on your end. When the **main** thread would call:

```
worker1.setOptionOfWork(2);
worker1.doInBackground();
```

then the *work* is done on that *main* thread. To be precise: the thread *invoking* the methods spends the time "doing" the work then.

But beyond that: of course something like this is possible. It is **your** worker implementation, so *you* are in **full** control. But you have to understand: in order to get this "correct" (and reasonable "architected") - a lot of work will be required:

- you need an appropriate data structure to **communicate** with the worker threads (for example a queue)
- your worker threads need to *periodically* check the status of that queue
- and from there: if you want to "change" what is happening, the main thread puts in a "command" into the queue. The worker thread reads the command, and acts accordingly.

As you can see, the "flow" is pretty simple - but this requires quite some implementation effort (and is easy to get wrong).

In that sense, my recommendation is: if your threads are doing so much work that you want to "cancel" them sometimes - then create smaller work packages. So instead of having one thread being busy for one task for 10 minutes - create many smaller tasks. And add those for execution. Then "cancel" means - not sending further "small" requests.

Such an architecture is easier to implement, and more robust in the long run.